# Is the address of memory mapped io programable

Tags: linux, kernel, hardware, bios

Is the address of memory mapped io programable ?

I Know it's hard-wired by hardware in old days.

on morden pc, is it can programable?

《Understanding linux kernel》said:

> bios establishes the mapping  during bootstraping, and report to the os kernel its initial memory address?

i am not sure what it means:

option 1:  it's address is programable.

option 2:  it's address is hardcode by hardware, it's just be reported to os by bios; because only bios know where it had be hard-wired.

So, is the address programable

Comment: By “the address” do you mean the physical address encoded on the bus  address lines, or the logical address where the mapped data is accessed by the process?

Comment: i mean the physical memory address.  it doesn't matter to page table.